# CocoaPods doesn't install Pods for iOS7 and Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking

I have created a new iOS Project with Xcode 5 and iOS7. When installing "AFNetworking" or "RestKit" pods. I get this error message.

```
[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 4.3) is not compatible with `AFNetworking 
(1.3.1)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 5.0 - OS X 10.7.
```

I have been looking for ways to solve this and nothing has came up. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure your Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'AFNetworking'
# other pods
```

That's because `AFNetworking` requires iOS 5+.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I will accept your answer when the timer runs out.

Comment: Also if you need to target older iOS versions you should rather choose an older AFNetworking version `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 0.10.1'`, etc.