# CocoaPods Error - The platform of the target `Pods` (OS X 10.6) is not compatible with

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods

I tried installing my CocoaPods with `pod install` and a `Podfile` that looks like

```
platform :osx

pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.1.8'
```

But I got the error

```
[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (OS X 10.6) is not compatible with `ReactiveCocoa (2.1.8)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 5.0 - OS X 10.7.
```

My deployment target is OSX 10.9 and the SDK is 10.9 so I'm not sure where it's getting OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The solution is to just specify a platform version in the `Podfile`

> platform :osx, '10.7'

I found that the default platform for CocoaPods is 10.6 on OS X and 4.3 on iOS currently.  The CocoaPods website describes it [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform).  It does not seem to care about or sniff out platform versions from the Xcode Project file.

A [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265674/cocoapods-doesnt-install-pods-for-ios7-and-xcode-5) appears for iOS projects apparently.

> [!] The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 4.3) is not compatible with...